# Что не так с моим запросом?

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно узнать количество связанных записей в двух таблицах. У меня получился следующий запрос:

```
select
       main.id
       count(news.id) as news,
       count(articles.id) as articles
from main
    LEFT JOIN news ON main.id = news.main_id
    LEFT JOIN articles ON main.id = articles.main_id
group by main.id
order by news desc;
```

В итоге я получаю значения в полях news и articles перемноженные друг на друга.
Если делаю два запроса по одному джойну, то получаю корректные данные. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: ну собственно все именно по тому, что данные перемножаются. да, join себя так ведут. они стараются выдать все варианты сопоставления строк в таблицах между собой по указанным критериям. Если скорость запроса позволяет, замените просто count на `count(distinct news.id)` что бы получить кол-во уникальных

Comment: А еще у вас какая то ошибка в articles. Вы в ON сравниваете два поля таблицы articles между собой, а не с другими таблицами. В итоге запрос выдаст каждую из строк первых двух таблиц со всеми строками таблицы articles подходящими под условие

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое за комментарий. Это именно то, что нужно. Напишите его в ответы, я отмечу решением.

Comment: @Mike и опечатка была в запросе, спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, join себя так ведут. они стараются выдать все варианты сопоставления строк в таблицах между собой по указанным критериям. И когда в двух таблицах находится более 1 записи по подходящим условиям происходит перемножение.

Самый простой способ посчитать количество, это применить ключевое слово distinct в count, для получения уникальных id:

```
select
       main.id
       count(distinct news.id) as news,
       count(distinct articles.id) as articles
 from main
 LEFT JOIN news ON main.id = news.main_id
 LEFT JOIN articles ON main.id = articles.main_id
group by main.id
order by news desc;
```

Но под капотом перемножение все равно происходит, мы лишь избавляемся от последствий. Что может вести к слишком медленному выполнению. В ряде случаев лучше применять последовательную склейку:

```
select x.id, max(news) news, count(articles.id) as articles
  from (
    select main.id, count(news.id) as news
      from main
      LEFT JOIN news ON main.id = news.main_id
      group by main.id
  ) x
 LEFT JOIN articles ON x.id = articles.main_id
group by x.id
order by news desc
```

Или группировать строки до одной заранее, перед склейкой (только в подобных указанному случаях, когда выборка действительно затрагивает все строки таблиц):

```
select main.id, news, articles
  from main
  LEFT JOIN (select main_id, count(1) as news from news group by main_id) n
         ON main.id = n.main_id
  LEFT JOIN (select main_id, count(1) as articles from articles group by main_id) a
         ON main.id = a.main_id
 order by news desc;
```

Так же возможно применение смешанных техник из вышеприведенных и еще нескольких, в зависимости от конкретной ситуации